# How to use webpack 5 configs in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

I am trying to add `experiments` to the webpack config but am unable to determine what I am doing wrong.

my environment:

- yarn@1.22.5
- node@12.13.0

I created a brand new next app with `npx create-next-app blog`

Based on what [I have read](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-5#webpack-5-support-beta) I need to add a resolutions property to the *package.json* like so:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "next": "10.0.6",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1"
},
"resolutions": {
  "webpack": "5.21.2"
}
```

And then in *next.config.js* I have the following:

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");
console.log(webpack.version); // 5.21.2
module.exports = {
  webpack: function (config, options) {
    console.log(options.webpack.version); // 4.44.1
    config.experiments = {};
    return config;
  },
};
```

and when I `yarn dev` I get the following error:

```js
- configuration[0] has an unknown property 'experiments'.
```

If you notice the required module webpack version is `5.21.2` but the version being used inside the config settings is `4.44.1`.

Comment: What next version?

Comment: @felixmosh 10.0.6

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Starting from Next.js v11 Webpack 5 [is now the default](https://nextjs.org/docs/upgrading#webpack-5) for all Next.js applications:

> Webpack 5 is now the default for all Next.js applications. If you did not have custom webpack configuration your application is already using webpack 5. If you do have custom webpack configuration you can refer to the [Next.js webpack 5 documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5) for upgrading guidance.

For prior versions of Next.js you need to set a flag for it in `next.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  future: {
    webpack5: true,
  },
  webpack: function (config, options) {
    console.log(options.webpack.version); // Should be webpack v5 now
    config.experiments = {};
    return config;
  },
};
```

And you can still use webpack 4 while upgrading to the latest version of Next.js by adding the `webpack5: false` flag

```js
module.exports = {
  // Note: no `future` key here
  webpack5: false,
}
```

Comment: I did beat you by a few seconds, but there goes an upvote nonetheless!

Comment: @juliomalves or Danila where is the documentation for that future property?

Comment: @juliomalves yes, you were faster by 12 seconds! Not sure why my answer was picked :)

Answer (score 23):

Since Next.js 11 webpack 5 is now used by default, with no extra configuration.

You can still use webpack 4 by setting the `webpack5` to `false` in `next.config.js`.

```js
module.exports = {
    webpack5: false
}
```

---

Prior to Next.js 11, there's a `future` flag that can be enabled for Webpack 5 in `next.config.js`.

```js
module.exports = {
    future: {
        webpack5: true
    },
    webpack: function (config, options) {
        console.log(options.webpack.version); // 5.18.0
        config.experiments = {};
        return config;
    }
};
```

Comment: thank you for answering, I give you a +1 for also answering

Comment: This is now documented by Next.js: [Webpack 5 Adoption](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5).

Answer (score 5):

Official Docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5

> Goto **`next.config.js`**

**Add** the snippet below with *`future flag`*

```
  future: {
    webpack5: true,
  }
```

My **next.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
  webpackDevMiddleware: (config) => {
    config.watchOptions = {
      poll: 1000,
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
    };

    return config;
  },
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, "styles")],
  },
  future: {
    webpack5: true,
  },
};
```

**Features**

[image: Features of webpack 5 as mentioned in Official Docs]