# sw-precache-webpack-plugin cause error on last version of Next Js

Tags: webpack, next.js

I used `sw-precache-webpack-plugin` on my NextJs application and it works totally fine.

I want to update the version of NextJs from 10.0.8 to the latest version (currently is 11.0.2) when I update it I get this error, which doesn't let the app compile:

```
TypeError: outputFileSystem.mkdirp is not a function
at route/to/my/project/node_modules/sw-precache-webpack-plugin/lib/index.js:241:26
```

When I remove the use of `sw-precache-webpack-plugin` my project start working but I need this package.

I tried it on different node version like v10.16.0 , v12.19.0, v14.15.0, v15.8.0, v16.9.1. but I get the same result all the time.

Does anybody have the same issue?

Comment: Next.js v11.x has webpack-5 enabled by default. The plugin you have referenced is probably not compatible with webpack-5. Also it's source hasn't been updated in around 4 years, and the author has mentioned that it is no longer being actively maintained. To make it work, you need to either switch back to webpack-4 (Ref. second part of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66125280/11613622)) or use some other plugin.

Comment: Thanks, That's work. I just use the webpack-4 on the last version of NextJS and It resolves all the problems

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/workbox-webpack-plugin. I ran into the same issue and found this plugin is comparable to the sw-precache-webpack-plugin.